# Bison + Flex SQL parser

Tags: sql, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am looking for a lightweight and simple SQL-99 parser in Bison + Flex (parser + lexer).

I've found this BNF grammar -> http://savage.net.au/SQL/, but there is no lexer included.
I'd use PostgreSQL's .y e .l files (in `src/backend/parser` of the distribution), but it looks too much complex for my purpose.

I don't need any semantic actions, just a YACC grammar (.y), and a Flex lexer (.l).

Comment: _"lightweight and simple SQL-99 parser"_, I don't think "lightweight" and "simple" can be applied to SQL parsers... :)

Answer (score 6):

hi there is a solution in google projects yaxx:

yac [file](http://yaxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sql/sql2.y)
lex [file](http://yaxx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/sql/scn2.l)

hope that helps you :)

Comment: Sadly, the file links are dead